# Blender Greace Pencil - 2D view captures object from the top

Tags: animation, camera, grease-pencil, 2d

I have worked with Blender a while back, however this is my first time using greace pencil.
I have drawn an object and made sure I drew it in the right view. However, when I click the camera to go to 2D view, the object shows only from the top. The same happens when I use the shortcut ctrl+alt+0. However, when I rotate out of 2d into 3d view, I see that the camera is aligned to face the object from the front, as is supposed to do.
I also tried rotating the object around any axis, however it stays perpendicular to the view if I am in camera 2d view.
Has anyone a solution how to fix this issue? I have also attached to screenshots, how the camera faces the object in 3d view and how it looks, when going into 2d.

[image: Object from y axis, how it is supposed to be]Object from y axis, how it is supposed to be
[image: Object when camera view activated or ctrl+alt+0]Object when camera view activated or ctrl+alt+0

I added another object (here a second tree) to the scene. rotating this object seperately from the camera works fine. Nor it is right in front of it in 2d, as well as in 3d view. However everytime I try rotating the first tree as well, the camera view is screwed again. Could it be, that this object is somehow linked to the camera, so they cannot be moved seperately?

[image: 3d view with 2nd tree rotated, but first tree stuck perpendicular to camera]3d view with 2nd tree rotated, but first tree stuck perpendicular to camera